# How to process a file being uploaded and renamed in a shiny application

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple shiny app below. In this app I want the user to be able to upload his own csv and then automatically this will be added as a choice in the checkbox group below the other dataset "D.B" (which I create in my original app). Then when the user chooses a file it will be displayed as a table.

Here I have managed to rename the uploaded file. However I can not then connect the renamed table with `renderTable()` while keeping the "changing name" ability.

```
# Define UI for data upload app ----
    ui <- fluidPage(

      # App title ----
      titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

       # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
      sidebarLayout(

        # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
        sidebarPanel(

           # Input: Select a file ----
           fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                    multiple = FALSE,
                    accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")),
          checkboxGroupInput("datasetSelector","Data Files", choices=c("D.B")),
          textInput("filename","Set Filename",value = "Set Name")

        ),

        # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
          mainPanel(

          # Output: Data file ----
          tableOutput("contents")

        ) 
      )
    )
    #server.r
    server <- function(input, output, session) {

      observeEvent(input$filename, {

      req(input$file1)
      Name<-input$filename
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"datasetSelector", choices=c("D.B",Name))
      })

      observeEvent(input$file1, {

        Data<-input$file1$datapath
        Name<-input$filename
        New <- read.csv(Data)
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"datasetSelector", 
          choices=c("D.B",input$file1$name))
      })

      D.B <- reactive({
        if("D.B"%in% input$datasetSelector){
          x <- read.csv("something.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
        }
      })

      output$contents <- renderTable({
        New
       })
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution.

This solution uses the ability of shiny inputs to take named lists. In a named list the label is the display name and the value is what is returned. E.g. `c("a" = 1, "b" = 2)` will display the labels `a` and `b` in the UI, but will return values of `1` and `2` in the server.

Because you want one of your labels to come from an input, it is necessary to build the ordered list in two parts. First, the values and then the labels. E.g. `mylist = c(1,2)` sets up the values then `names(mylist) = c("a","b")` assigns the labels.

Here is the code I had working:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")),
      checkboxGroupInput("datasetSelector","Data Files", choices=c("D.B" = "original")),
      textInput("filename","Set Filename",value = "Set Name")

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Data file ----
      tableOutput("contents")

    ) 
  )
)
#server.r
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$filename, {

    req(input$file1)
    Name<-input$filename
    # make list
    choices = c("original", "loaded")
    # assign labels to list
    names(choices) = c("D.B", Name)
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"datasetSelector", choices=choices)
  })

  observeEvent(input$file1, {

    Data<-input$file1$datapath
    Name<-input$filename
    New <- read.csv(Data)
    # make list
    choices = c("original", "loaded")
    # assign labels to list
    names(choices) = c("D.B", Name)
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"datasetSelector", choices=choices)
  })

  D.B <- reactive({
    if("D.B"%in% input$datasetSelector){
      x <- read.csv("something.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
    }
  })

  output_table = reactive({
    if("original" %in% input$datasetSelector)
      return(D.B())
    if("loaded" %in% input$datasetSelector)
      return(read.csv(input$file1$datapath))
  })


  output$contents <- renderTable({
    output_table()
  })
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```